# Give permissions to users to edit Drupal Views content

Tags: 7, views

How to give permission to users to edit the content that are in Views. 
In Views the FORMAT is:

Format: Unformatted list | Settings
Show: Content | Full content

Thank you in advance.

Comment: On "page settings" of views settings page, you can add permission there, is that what you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can control view page access using "Page settings" section on views settings page,

[image: Views page settings]

You can grant permission for **views edit** to any Role you like form permissions page.

admin -> people -> permission

[image: Permission page]

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have created a View as block and displayed this view in a page (like node/5). I want the page (node/5) to be editable by a user. Please help on this. If anything is unclear let me know.